# corroborar usuario existente en Android mediante API REST?

Tags: php, java, android, volley

Buen día yo realizo el alta de un usuario mediante una API REST. La insercion realiza correctamente.
Pero me encuentro con el problema de cómo corroborar si un usuario ya existe con el mismo DNI.
Comparto mi código:

```
private void altapersona(String URL) {
    String seleccion = spinnerSexos.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(seleccion.equals("Masculino")) {
        sexoBD= "1";
    }
    if(seleccion.equals("Femenino")) {
        sexoBD="2";
    }
    if(seleccion.equals("Otro")) {
        sexoBD="3";
    }
    StringRequest stringRequest= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alta exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                etdni.setText("");
                etapellido.setText("");
                etnombres.setText("");
                etestadocivil.setText("");
                etemail.setText("");
                etpassword.setText("");
            
        }
    }
```

Y el código PHP es: se me ocurrio hacer una consulta antes y ver si es vacio o no pero despues no se como obtener eso en el response del proyecto

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$dni=$_POST['dni']; //datos desde android studio
$apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
$nombres=$_POST['nombres'];
$sexo=$_POST['sexo_id'];
$provincia=$_POST['provincia'];
$estado=$_POST['estado'];
$estado_civil=$_POST['estado_civil'];
$usuario_id=$_POST['usuario_id'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$sql = "select * from personas where dni = '$dni'";
if (empty($sql)) {
    $consulta="insert into personas(dni,apellido, nombres, sexo_id, estado,estado_civil,usuario_id,email,pass) values('".$dni."','".$apellido."','".$nombres."','".$sexo."','".$estado."','".$estado_civil."','".$usuario_id."','".$email."','".$password."')";
    mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die (mysqli_error($conexion)); //agregado el mensaje 
    mysqli_close($conexion);
}
```

?>

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: No estás ejecutando el select para saber si ese registro existe.

Comment: Esto no sirve para determinar si ese registro existe: `if (empty($sql)) {`, ahí `$sql` es una cadena, nada más, debes ejecutar `$sql`, y luego verificar si trajo alguna fila, es la forma de determinar si existe una persona con ese DNI. Lee sobre los métodos Fetch de mysqli en el Manual de PHP. Luego, para consumir en Android, debes emitir un mensaje o un valor numérico o lo que sea, que te permita saber, en base a lo que has emitido, si el registro está repetido o se insertó uno nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos ya pude solucionar.
Dejo aporte por si alguien despues se encuentra ante la misma duda:
en el código PHP hice esta comprobación:

```
$consulta = "select * from personas where dni = '$dni'";
$resultado=$conexion-> query($consulta);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
if ($num_rows > 0) {
    echo json_encode("");
}
else {
```

//realiza la insercion
}

Y con el codigo JAVA:

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alta exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario existente con ese DNI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```